# Can I offload my App_Theme folder to a static domain

Tags: asp.net, optimization

Just finished reading the latest stackoverflow blog post about moving static content to a separate domain.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/

However my website makes extensive use of Themes for rebranding for our customers.  Is there a way of moving this data to a static domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any more information i dont see why not. Basicly you can offload all static content like pictures,css or any other files that not generated to a seperate domain.

If your wondering about spesfic files please provide details.

Comment: I was more concerned because its an ASP.NET special folder

Comment: I have not used a ASP.net Spesial folder for themes, i just use CSS files myself. But from what a search told me it seems this folder has css files and pictures so i see no reason why you cannot host that on a different domain.